# EF reference lookup

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I load list of invoices, and I also loaded list of customers, using the same context. If I want to display invoices in a grid, where one column will contain customer's name, I need to somehow fix-up the relationship between the invoices and the customers.

How can I do this?

Comment: Probably the best way is to throw away all your EF code and re-write everything in Perl ;)

Comment: Have you defined the relationship between customers and invoices in your mappings?

Comment: @w.brian. Yes, I have defined them in fluent mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that customers list was retrieved with MergeOption.NoTracking, so it was detached from context, and it could not look for relationship.